# Percent column in SQL using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table consisting of databases, tables, variables, values and the frequency count. I want to query this and create a [Percent] column which will be the frequency out of the total at variable level.

I have managed to join on the total, but the percentage calculating doesn't seem to be working. I am getting 0 for every Percent value.

```
select t1.[database], 
       t1.[table], 
       t1.[variable],
       t1.[value],
       t1.[frequency],
       t2.[vartotal],
       ([frequency]) / t2.vartotal *100 as [Percent]
from TestDB.dbo.Meta t1
join (select [database], [table_name], [variable], sum(frequency) as vartotal
    from TestDB.dbo.Meta
    group by [database], 
             [table], 
             [variable]) t2
on t1.[database]=t2.[database] and 
   t1.[table]=t2.[table] and 
   t1.[variable]=t2.[variable]
group by t1.[database], t1.[table_name], t1.variable, 
t1.[value], t1.[frequency], t2.[vartotal]
```

Why is returning zeroes for all percentage calculations?

Comment: INTEGER division... Do `[frequency] * 1.0`.

Comment: select 10 / 100 * 100, 10.0/100.0*100.0 -- this examples shows types matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division, so 1/2 = 0, not 0.5.  I usually just multiply by 1.0 to solve this problem:

```
  ([frequency] * 100.0 / t2.vartotal) as [Percent]
```

That said, you can use window functions for this calculation:

```
select . . .,
      sum(frequency) over (partition by database, table, variable) as vartotal,
       ([frequency] * 100.0 / sum(frequency) over (partition by database, table, variable) ) as [Percent]
from TestDB.dbo.Meta t1;
```

This is much simpler and should have better performance than your query.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an issue regarding what datatype frequency is. Try the following:
Also might want to add some extra parents to ensure order of operations.

```
select t1.[database], 
       t1.[table], 
       t1.[variable],
       t1.[value],
       t1.[frequency],
       t2.[vartotal],
       ((TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, [frequency])) / TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, t2.vartotal)) * 100 as [Percent]
from TestDB.dbo.Meta t1
join (select [database], [table_name], [variable], sum(frequency) as vartotal
    from TestDB.dbo.Meta
    group by [database], 
             [table], 
             [variable]) t2
on t1.[database]=t2.[database] and 
   t1.[table]=t2.[table] and 
   t1.[variable]=t2.[variable]
group by t1.[database], t1.[table_name], t1.variable, 
t1.[value], t1.[frequency], t2.[vartotal]
```

Comment: Don't you mean the opposite? (You want to go away from integer.)

Comment: Oh, I see. I will edit to try FLOAT instead. Thank you for catching my logic error.